# Transition matrix of reversible process.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am reading about time reversal for Markov Chain and I am not exactly sure I got it right. The chain is reversible means that $P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i)=P(X_{n} = j|X_{n+1}=i)$ is that correct? Now in general, if we don't know that the chain is reversible and if we don't know about any invariant distribution, how do we compute $P(X_{n} = j|X_{n+1}=i)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(X_n)$ be Markov$(\lambda, P)$, where $P$ is irreducible. Then $(X_n)$ is reversible if, for all $N\geq1$, the sequence $(X_{N-n})_{0\leq n\leq N}$ is also Markov$(\lambda,P)$. Implicitly this requires that our initial distribution $\lambda$ is invariant for $P$.

The main result is the following:

**Theorem:** Let $P$ be irreducible, and $\pi$ an invariant distribution. Suppose $(X_n)_{0\leq n\leq N}$ is Markov$(\pi,P)$. Then $(X_{N-n})_{0\leq n\leq N}$ is Markov$(\pi,\hat{P})$, where $\hat{P}=(\hat{p}_{ij})$ is the matrix satisfying
$$\pi_j\hat{p}_{ji}=\pi_ip_{ij},$$
for all $i,j$. Further, $\hat{P}$ is irreducible, and has $\pi$ as an invariant distribution.

The proof is fairly boring -- you can try it yourself if you wish. There are two things worth pointing out:

- The theorem says that a Markov chain, in equilibrium, is still a Markov chain when run backwards. The transition matrix could be different though.
- If we want time-symmety, we *must* begin in an equilibrium of the Markov chain. This is intuitively clear -- else convergence to an equilibrium gives us a clue as to which "direction" of time we're going in.

So if $X_n)$ is Markov$(\lambda,P)$, it is reversible iff $\hat{P}=P$, i.e. $$\lambda_jp_{ji}=\lambda_ip_{ij}$$
for all $i,j$. These are the *detailed balance* equations. To prove that a chain is reversible, you need to show that there is a distribution $\lambda$ satisfying these equations.

As an exercise, you might like to show that a simple symmetric random walk on a finite connected graph is reversible.

Comment: On the subject of "what's this concept for?", one important thing in applications is that you don't actually need to know $\pi$ to define $\hat{P}$. All you need to know about $\pi$ is basically $\frac{\pi_i}{\pi_j}$. You can know this ratio even if you only know $\pi$ up to a constant factor.

Comment: @jlammy and @Ian, Thank you. So the way it is written in the question is correct, since $P=\hat{P}$ means $P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i)=P(X_{n} = j|X_{n+1}=i)$ right? I don't really understand `Implicitly this requires that our initial distribution  is invariant for `, why is this?

Comment: @roi_saumon yep your claim is correct. That line is referring to the fact that if $(X_n)$ is reversible, then each $X_n$ must have the same distribution as $X_0$ (i.e. $\lambda$) so $\lambda$ is invariant. The second bullet point in my answer gives another perspective on this: if we aren't already in an invariant distribution, then convergence to equilibrium gives us a clue as to whether we're going forwards or backwards in the Markov chain.

Comment: @jlammy, I am still struggling. If $\pi$ was not an invariant distribution but suppose $(X_n)_{0\leq n\leq N}$ is Markov$(\pi,P)$ then $(X_{N-n})_{0\leq n\leq N}$ is Markov$(what?,\hat{P})$

Comment: @roi_saumon the answer to your question is $\pi P^n$, which is the distribution of $X_N$. This is why we need invariant distributions: so that the starting distributions of $X_0$ and the reversed chain $Y_0 = X_N$ are the same.

Comment: @jlammy, Okay I am starting to get it. But in this same scenario, where $\pi$ is not necessarily invariant, how to express $\hat{p}_{ij}$ in function of $p_{ij}$ (or $p_{ji}$)?

Comment: $$\hat{p}_{ij}(n)=\frac{\mathbb P(X_n=j, X_{n+1}=i)}{\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=i)} =\frac{p_{ji}\cdot\mathbb P(X_n=j)}{\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=i)}.$$ If $\pi$ isn't invariant, this number depends on the value of $n$, so the Markov chain is no longer homogenous. You see why I wanted to insist on $\pi$ invariant now :)

Comment: I think I get it now. From the definition you gave, $(X_n)$ is reversible if, for all $N\geq1$, the sequence $(X_{N-n})_{0\leq n\leq N}$ is also Markov$(\lambda,P)$. So we can take $N=1$, and so $X_1\to X_0$ must be Markov$(\lambda,P)$ (and also $X_0\to X_1$). So in particular its initial distribution $(\lambda P)_i = \mathbb{P}(X_1=i)=\lambda_i$ which implies that $\lambda P = \lambda$, so $\lambda$ is an invariant distribution. Is that it? I just think this concept is still a bit unclear since when I look at the diagram of a Markov chain, I often struggle to know if it is reversible or not.

Comment: @roi_saumon Reversibility is not strictly topological so you cannot simply read it off from the transition diagram. Topologically speaking, reversibility just requires every edge to have a reverse. But it also needs the probability fluxes on those two edges to exactly cancel each other out if the chain is in equilibrium. By contrast in the general situation, equilibrium can be attained by a balance of *all* edges connected to a given state *together*. The example of a deterministic cycle of at least three states as being *non*-reversible can help illustrate this.